# Returning promise data instead of array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am writing a web app that pushes a user's favourite movies using the movie ids and displays the movies.

The user's favourites are stored on mongo Atlas. In the api user file I have a GET request for a user's favourites.

**users/index.js**

```
router.get('/:userName/favourites', asyncHandler( async (req, res) => {
    const userName = req.params.userName;
    const user = await User.findByUserName(userName);
    res.status(200).json(user.favourites);
}));
```

Using Postman I can confirm it returns an array of movie ids.
On the React app side I have a fetch request.

**api/api.js**

```
export const getFavourites = (username) => {
  return fetch(
    `/api/users/${username}/favourites`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': window.localStorage.getItem('token')
    }
}
  )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      return json;
      
    });
};
```

Using `console.log(json)' I can see that it returns the array list.

The problem occurs when I call `getFavourites(username)`. It returns this...

```
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
​
<state>: "fulfilled"
​
<value>: Array(12) [ 436270, 1013860, 505642, … ]
​
<prototype>: Promise.prototype { … }
index.js:28
```

The array is there with the correct Ids but I cannot access this with the Promise in the way.

I have looked online with related issues but they have not been helpful.

Comment: Add another `.then()` handler to the returned promise, or `await` it in an `async` function.

Comment: `getFavourites` does a `fetch`, which is asynchronous. Try `await getFavourites(username)` to get the asynchronous result.

Answer (score 0):

**Use await before res.json() as it has to wait for promise to be complete its state.**

i have used **async and used await** in below example :

```js
export const getFavourites = (username) => {
  return fetch(
    `/api/users/${username}/favourites`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': window.localStorage.getItem('token')
    }
}
  )
    .then(async (res) => await res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      return json;
      
    });
};
```

Comment: That didnt work unfortunately